# update subset of all collections in mongodb with a criteria

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying out to update collections in the mongoDB. The structures are like this:

**obj_100**

```
{
    id: 123,
    name: test_1,
    type : [{
        name: test_1,
        version : 34,
    }
   {
        name: test_65,
        version : 344,
    }]
}
```

**obj_101**

```
{
    id: 124,
    name: test_2,
    type: [{
        name: test_2,
        version: 3,
    }
    {
        name: test_25,
        version: 323,
    }]
}
....
....
```

Now, I want to replace the string "test" in the `name` (wherever it is - in this case, it is under the `{obj {name}}` and under `{obj {type {name}}` in all the collections, to "production" so that it looks like,

**obj_100**

```
{
    id: 123,
    name: production_1,
    type : [{
        name: production_1,
        version : 34,
    }
    {
        name: production_65,
        version : 344,
    }] 
}
```

**obj_101**

```
{
    id: 124,
    name: production_2,
    type: [{
        name: production_2,
        version: 3,
    }
    {
        name: production_25,
        version: 323,
    }]
}
....
....
```

I tried this,

$MONGO_ROOT/bin/mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/cyclops --eval 'db.stages.find().forEach(function(doc){doc.name=doc.name.replace(/msmaster2int/, "test");db.stages.save(doc);});'

The above is just changing the "name". Similarly i want to update the data in the array as well.

can anyone help me out in this

Answer (score 0):

You should use `multi :true` in update like this :

```
db.stages.update({"name":/test/,"type.name":/test/},{"$set":{"name":"production","type.name":"production"}},false,true )
```

Here I update `name:test` to `name:production`,first searched `name:test` using regular expression and replace it using new string. But after looking your edited question and expected output I think you should use [mongo bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operation using following script

```
var bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;

db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(data) {
    var objectName = data.name; // first get name from outside object
    var regex = /(test_)(\d)/;
    objectName = objectName.replace(regex, "production_$2"); //replace name to production


    for(var ii = 0; ii < data.type.length; ii++) { //iterate over type arry
      var typeName = data.type[ii].name; // find type array name 
      var regex = /(test_)(\d)/;
      typeName = typeName.replace(regex, "production_$2"); //replace same here 

      var typeKey = "type." + ii + ".name";
      var updoc = {
        "$set": {}
      };

      updoc["$set"]["name"] = objectName; // set both name and type.name 
      updoc["$set"][typeKey] = typeName;

      bulk.find({
        "_id": data._id
      }).update(updoc);

      counter++;

      if(counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(); //execute bulk update here
        bulk = db.collectionName.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
      }

    }

  })

if(counter % 1000 != 0) bulk.execute();
```

Comment: hi Yogesh, its again says " 0 rows updated".. could you please explain me what are u doing?

Comment: what script is this? shell scripting?

Comment: @LogeshwariRam not a shell script it is Java Script, just copy paste above code in mongo shell and check documents updated or not.

Comment: i want a python script.. there are lot of code on this mongdb in the script. hve to append this code as well to the same script. can u pls change acc. to python if possible?

Comment: $MONGO_ROOT/bin/mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/cyclops --eval 'db.stages.find().forEach({name:/msmaster2int/}).forEach(function (doc) {doc.consumers.forEach(function (event) {event.name=event.name.replace(/msmaster2int/, "test");});db.collection.save(doc);});'

Comment: @LogeshwariRam I am not too much aware about python script, but I think you should first run this script on mongo shell and check this script update your documents structure or not. If yes then try to convert this script into python script, I will also try to make this script for python :)